# How to figure out whether the current login user is admin or not in the account theme (in ftl file)

Tags: themes, keycloak, roles

Is there a way to identify the user role in a custom keycloak theme?
How to figure out whether the current login user is admin or not in the account theme (in account.ftl file)
I'm using keycloak-20.0.2

```
<#if user?has_content && user.realmRoles?seq_contains('admin')>  -->
        <!-- User is an admin -->
        <h1>Welcome, Admin!</h1>
    <#else>
        <!-- User is not an admin -->
        <h1>Welcome, User!</h1>
    </#if>
```

error: user has evaluated to null or missing